# Supporting autorotation for iOS5 and iOS6

Tags: ios, objective-c

I wanted to implement such autorotation for learning purposes.

When device runs on iPad support **all** orientations, when on iPhone **don't allow** autorotation.

I want the autorotation to work for **both** iOS5 and iOS6.

What code should I write?

PS. The below approach doesn't seem to work:

```
 - (BOOL) shouldAutorotate
{
    return  ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad);
}

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
     if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
     {
         return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
     }
     else
     {
         return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
     }

}
```

Comment: That's because that code is iOS 6 only.  Just implement the iOS 5 method in addition.  I won't tell you what it is but it is listed in the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) in the **Configuring the View Rotation Settings** section

Comment: @borrrden: So you say if I want to support autorotation for iOS5 and iOS6, I should provide implementations for both versions? PS. Now I added code for iOS5 - which works, the code for iOS 6 doesn't work however, seems I have some mistake there...

Comment: You have to be specific (i.e. How does it not work.  Does it not rotate at all, does it only rotate to certain ones, etc etc)

Comment: @borrden: Given the code I posted - when I run the Simulator for iOS 6, both iPhone and iPad versions support all orientations, except UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortraitUpsideDown. (Which is not what I wanted as I mentioned in my post). On 5.0 simulators everything works as I wanted...

Comment: One more thing to note is that the `supportedInterfaceOrientations` method will only be called on the root view controller of your window.  Make sure that it is actually making it to that method.  It sounds like that method is not being called, and the system is defaulting to the orientations defined in your App Settings.

Comment: @borrrden: The root view controller of my window is a Navigation Controller. The code I posted above is implemented for a ViewController, which sits on the stack of NavigationControllers view controllers. What to do in such case?

Comment: Move it to your navigation controller then, or if it depends on the child then have the navigation controller query the child controller.

Comment: @borrrden: I am not sure how I can query the child as you mentioned, bust as I mentioned above, my Nav Controller is created programatically in app delegate, so I don't know how to add these methods in such a case..